# The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have web.config inside the Views folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="PartyInvites" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also make sure  the solutions Web.config is updated

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But when i look at the views, i still get the error

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Viewbag' does not exist in
>   the current context

Comment: I don't know, it was pre-generated with it.

Comment: @Adil, A `web.config` file is required in the view folder

Comment: Have you also checked the main `web.config` file for any possible version issues?

Comment: Ill check later, im trying to update sdk to 2.6 to try my luck

Comment: I didn't understand the real situation but in my case I went in the Properties selected a previous target framework (from 4.6 to 4.5.2, recompiled it and all disappeared. Then I returned to 4.6 doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue is an isolated case, VS tells me it get screwed after i updated some extension, i cannot remember what extension made it like this so i just repaired the installation of VS and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Visual Studio 2015. It was resolved by updating the .Net Framework to use 4.5.2 instead of 4.0. This is done in the *Properties* page of the project.

Comment: You should post some reference site on your answer or more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue regardless of having all the correct configuration done in the web.config file.

Found out to be some bad files in the Component Cache, preventing the Razor views from recognising ViewBag, Model, and HtmlHelpers. Deleting these files solved the problem (good versions of these files were created next time I opened Visual Studio).

**Please follow below path to discover the files:**

```
C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

**Delete all four files:**

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.catalogs
3. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err
4. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.external

I closed my project, deleted the files on that path and reopened my project, cleaned the solution and built it again and the problem was solved

Deleting your Temporary ASP.NET Files also helps. C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Thanks!